# Missing BEGIN and END?

Tags: sql-server

I am pretty sure what is going on but wanted to get some ideas from my fellow SQL Server Travelers (actually it is fairly obvious what is going on but I think makes for an interesting discussion).

Riddle me this Batman... what is up with this?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ToBeDropped
AS
BEGIN
PRINT 'Drop me!';
END
DROP PROCEDURE ToBeDropped;
```

What happens? My first thought was the procedure gets created then immediately dropped. Wrongo! And you probably thought the same unless you already knew this about issue from before... admit it!

In SSMS hit Ctrl-T to switch Query Results to Text. Then run the following (or you could script the new procedure ToBeDropped):

```
SELECT m.[definition]
FROM sys.sql_modules AS m INNER JOIN sys.objects AS obj
ON m.object_id = obj.object_id
WHERE obj.name = 'ToBeDropped';
```

Next run the procedure:

```
EXECUTE ToBeDropped;
```

The rerun the above sys.sql_modules query or attempt to script the object. You can't because it no longer exists.

Hmmm... What's going on here? Clearly there is an implicit BEGIN and END to the while procedure, similar to the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ToBeDropped
AS
BEGIN
BEGIN
PRINT 'Drop me!';
END
DROP PROCEDURE ToBeDropped;
END;
```

Which when formatted better looks like the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ToBeDropped
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Drop me!';
    END

    DROP PROCEDURE ToBeDropped;
END ;
```

I am not a big fan of implicit behavior. I prefer being explicit. TSQL is moving in the direction of becoming more "real" - see the semicolon and all the CLR functionality now available or potentially available in TSQL. I would like to see a CREATE PROCEDURE body be required to have at least 1 BEGIN and END pair - heck make { be an alias/synonym for BEGIN and } an alias/synonym for END - and we would be one step closer to TSQL turning into C#.

Thoughts? Opinions? Thanks!

Comment: This is not a discussion site. This is a Q&A site. Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Comment: This question might be "better enough to stay" if you re-write it from the perspective of http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 2):

drop procedure is part of the proc and the proc won't get dropped until you call the proc

This will create and drop the proc, notice the `GO` this is the batch terminator, if you don't have that the drop statement will be part of the proc itself

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ToBeDropped
AS
BEGIN
PRINT 'Drop me!';
END
GO
DROP PROCEDURE ToBeDropped;
```

when you do this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ToBeDropped
AS
BEGIN
PRINT 'Drop me!';
END
DROP PROCEDURE ToBeDropped;
```

the proc gets created but doesn't get dropped until you call the proc

```
EXEC  ToBeDropped
```

this has nothing to do with BEGIN but because the DROP PROC is part of the procedure itself and doesn't get executed until you call it

when you try to xeecute the proc again

```
EXEC  ToBeDropped
```

you get the following message

```
Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 1
Could not find stored procedure 'ToBeDropped'.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather open ended question that will most likely be shut down for vagueness. Maybe you could re-ask on Meta Overflow?

However, before it does get shut down, the reasoning as far as I know it is not because of a BEGIN and END. It is because of a GO. A create procedure puts all the logic underneath it until it hits the end of the file or a GO. So, this is the explicit value that you are looking for:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ToBeDropped
AS
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Drop me!';
END
--Completes the procedure creation
GO
DROP PROCEDURE ToBeDropped;
```

Comment: This question would be closed in a hail of downvotes on Meta. Meta is for questions about the network, bug reports, suggestions, user support.